# Take number after floating point

Tags: python, ieee-754, bin

I have this value :

```
a = 1.01010101
```

And i need to take all the numbers after the point, 
convert them into an int.
Create a new variable and put this int in an new variable.
So i need an output like this

```
b = 01010101
```

I can't make this:

```
a -= 1
b = a*(10**8)
```

because I don't know the number before the point.
Is it also possible to do it without writing a new function?
Sorry for my english.
Have a good day

Comment: Are you sure you want to have an integer? Your example is ambigous since the integer will not have a leading zero. Do you want to have '01010101' (str), 1010101 (int) as result which is a big difference. If you really want to have the integer the answer below is correct.

Comment: That doesn't make sense for multiple reasons, including floating-point representation issues *and* integer representation issues.

Comment: Or are you looking for something like 0.01010101?

Answer (score 1):

The `math.trunc()` function will give you the integer part:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.trunc(1.01010101)
1
```

you can then subtract, however you'll likely run into ieee floating point issues that may be surprising:

```
>>> a = 1.01010101
>>> a -= math.trunc(a)
>>> a
0.010101010000000077
>>> b = a * 10**8
>>> b
1010101.0000000077
```

in many cases you can just truncate the last number to get the expected integer, but I'd suggest reading https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html to get a deeper understanding.

Python has a `decimal` module that handles base-10 arithmetic more faithfully:

```
import decimal.Decimal as D
>>> a = D('1.01010101')
>>> a
Decimal('1.01010101')
>>> math.trunc(a)
1
>>> a -= math.trunc(a)
>>> a
Decimal('0.01010101')
>>> a * 10**8
Decimal('1010101.00000000')
>>> b = int(a * 10**8)
>>> b
1010101
```

in this version there will be no floating point artifacts in the `b = ...` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
a = 1.01010101
b = str(a).split('.')[1]
```

This should give you "01010101".

Comment: Thk's, i'll check rigth now :)

Comment: I've tried without the int(), and now i have what i wanted but with wrong type. It's okay. Thank's a lot :)

Comment: Maybe in decimal but not in binary :)

Comment: @FatihAkman oh. it sounded like you were trying to get it as an integer

Comment: How could it be an integer? You would get the same result for 1.00023 and 1.23 which would be 23. Would be the same in decimal. Numbers don't have leading zeros. That is what the decimal point is for.